# Dynamic LINQ query to get Field value from Database

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dynamic-linq

is it possible?

```
Public String Get_Filed_By_Id(string table_Name,String Field_Name,string PK_val)
{
    string strRes="";
    using(mydbcontext db=new mydbcontext())
    {
      var x=db.table_Name.Where(p=>p.Id=PK_val).FirstOrDefault().Field_Name;
      strRes=Convert.Tostring(x);
    }
 return strRes;
}
```

OR

```
var x=(from o in db.table_Name where o.Id=PK_val select o.Field_Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here, i'm passing `Table_Name`,`Column_Name` and the Condition value(`PK_val`) to Get the `Column_Name` from `Table_Name` within a Certain Condition(`Id=Pk_val`).

**Is it possible??**

Comment: well if you need that kind of functionality  the first thing on mind is reflection (but not inside IQueryable): var tableItem= db.table_Name.Where(p=>p.Id=PK_val).FirstOrDefault(); var x=tableItem.GetType().GetProperty(FieldName).GetValue(tabelItem, null);

Comment: have you considered using repository pattern?

Comment: @Arashjo no, can you show me the way, make an answer??

Comment: user3540365 ,just  a moment plz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Is it possible??**

Yes, it is.

First, some helpers:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    internal static class DbHelpers
    {
        public static object GetColumnById(this object dbContext, string tableName, string columnName, object id)
        {
            var table = (IQueryable)dbContext.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(dbContext, null);
            var row = Expression.Parameter(table.ElementType, "row");
            var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(row, "Id"), Expression.Constant(id)), row);
            var column = Expression.Property(row, columnName);
            var selector = Expression.Lambda(column, row);
            var query = Call(Where.MakeGenericMethod(row.Type), table, filter);
            query = Call(Select.MakeGenericMethod(row.Type, column.Type), query, selector);
            var value = Call(FirstOrDefault.MakeGenericMethod(column.Type), query);
            return value;
        }
        private static readonly MethodInfo Select = GetGenericMethodDefinition<
            Func<IQueryable<object>, Expression<Func<object, object>>, IQueryable<object>>>((source, selector) =>
            Queryable.Select(source, selector));
        private static readonly MethodInfo Where = GetGenericMethodDefinition<
            Func<IQueryable<object>, Expression<Func<object, bool>>, object>>((source, predicate) =>
            Queryable.Where(source, predicate));
        private static readonly MethodInfo FirstOrDefault = GetGenericMethodDefinition<
            Func<IQueryable<object>, object>>(source =>
            Queryable.FirstOrDefault(source));
        private static MethodInfo GetGenericMethodDefinition<TDelegate>(Expression<TDelegate> e)
        {
            return ((MethodCallExpression)e.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        }
        private static object Call(MethodInfo method, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return method.Invoke(null, parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

and now your function:

```
public string Get_Field_By_Id(string table_Name, string field_Name, string PK_val)
{
    using (var db = new mydbcontext())
        return Convert.ToString(db.GetColumnById(table_Name, field_Name, PK_val));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible with EntityFramework actually(as far as I know). If you only needed the field by its name, then you could have used @Den's proposed solution. But you want to specify the table name too as a parameter. So I suggest you to use standard Sql Connector api, and build the query string with the parameters you provide.

Check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/837599/Using-Csharp-to-connect-to-and-query-from-a-SQL-da) for usage of standard sql connector api.

Answer (score 1):

*I had this question too ,I know this is not exactly what you want and you need write more code but it's much cleaner than those you want to write.*
**Using repository pattern**
For every table you should have a model class and Repository class.
Consider this code(this code from one of my project)
This is my comment table(this can be anything with or without navigation property)

```
  public sealed class Comment
{
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int? PageId { get; set; }
    public Page Page { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Comment[] ChildComments { get; set; }
}
```

RepositoryComment

```
  public sealed class CommentRepository : BaseRepository<Comment>
{
    public CommentRepository(BabySitterContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

and a base class that you send your query with table name(here model) and field(you can extend clas for more functionality)

```
public class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected BabySitterContext Context;
    private readonly PluralizationService _pluralizer = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
    public BaseRepository(BabySitterContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }
    public bool Add(T t)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(t);
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    public bool Update(T t)
    {
        var entityName = GetEntityName<T>();

        object originalItem;
        var key = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey(entityName, t);
        if (((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem))
        {
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, t);
        }
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    public void Attach(T t)
    {
        if (t == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("t");
        }

        Context.Set<T>().Attach(t);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Remove(T t)
    {
        if (t == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("t");
        }
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(t);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter.Expand());
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
    private string GetEntityName<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return string.Format("{0}.{1}", ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.DefaultContainerName, _pluralizer.Pluralize(typeof(TEntity).Name));

    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByBusinessKey(T entity)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For any other table just make model class and reposiotry then inherite from base class

Using code

```
 var context = new BabySitterContext();
 var  _commentRepository = new CommentRepository(context);
 var comment = _commentRepository.Get(x => x.PostId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but in this way

```
Public String Get_Filed_By_Id(string table_Name,String Field_Name,string PK_val)
{
    string strRes="";
    using(mydbcontext db=new mydbcontext())
    {
      var x=db.table_Name.Where(p=>p.Id=PK_val).Select(b=>b.Field_Name).FirstOrDefault();
      strRes=Convert.Tostring(x);
    }
 return strRes;
}
```

Comment: Not gonna Work, i'm trying to pass the `Table_Name` and 'Field_value' as a `Parameter`

Comment: then use query, like db.database.ExecuteSQLQuery or something like this which takes a string (query) as parameter.

Comment: i believe this way possible, but guess it would be broad, but i want to see the way.