# Get column by table name entity framework reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, dataset

I need to get column name and value from a table which I know only the name.
I try lot of stuff but without success.

I use this for get my table :

```
var table = oSession.ctx.GetType()
                       .GetProperty("country")
                       .GetValue(oSession.ctx, null);
```

I'm lock with that I can't retrieve the informations of my columns .. 
Perhaps I have already try this :

```
List<string> columnsNames = table.GetType().GetFields().Select(field => field.Name).ToList();
```

Thx for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `((IQueryable)table).ElementType.GetProperties()` as a starting point. Also you can get some ideas from [Dynamic LINQ query to get Field value from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219773/dynamic-linq-query-to-get-field-value-from-database/32321711#32321711)

Answer (score 0):

you can probably try using GetProperties()
table.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => !(p.GetMethod.IsVirtual || p.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)).ToList()